# proof of continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have a question about multivariate analysis. This is the exercise:

Fix a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^m$ with $f(0) = 0$. Let $G : \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}^m$ be a
function such that $G(x, t) =
\frac{f(xt)}{t}$
for all $t \neq 0$.
Prove that:

- If $G$ is continuous and $G(\cdot, 0)$ is linear, then $f$ is continuous everywhere, differentiable at zero,
  and $G(x, 0) = Df(0)(x)$
- Conversely, if $f$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable at zero, we can set $G(x, 0) =
  Df(0)(x)$ so that G is continuous.

I am not sure where to begin. Could I proof continuity of f by the definition of continuity? So using $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) =f(a)$ and then somehow substituting $G$ in there? And to proof that $G(x, 0) = Df(0)(x)$ again, should this be done using the definition? So by showing that $Df(0)(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h}$. In that case, how should I use the linearity of $G(\cdot,0)$?

For the second question should I just proof continuity of $G$ in the point $G(x,0)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Df(0)(x)$? Is $Df(0)$ not simply a matrix not depending on $x$? Do you mean the directional derivative perhaps in the direction of $x$?